# How to use update in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Search for 'no' among documents in a collection and retrieve a single document.

There are several fields in it.

for example name:name , age:age, gender : gender...

How do I change my gender here?

How should it be implemented inside the if statement in the code below?

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collection")whereEqualTo("no",Integer.parseInt(no)).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                String member;
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        

                          document. ///here 
                          
                  //firestore.collection("team_list").document().update("gender","testgender");
                  //This code doesn't work.


                    }}
                } 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generates a document reference with a random document ID:

```
firestore.collection("team_list").document()
```

That is definitely not what you want.  You need a reference to the document you found instead of a random ID.

Do this instead:

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
    document.getReference().update("gender","testgender");
}
```

`document.getReference()` returns a reference to the document you found in the results, so you can use that to perform the update.

Comment: Thank you.
This is the answer i wanted. :)